# LitJsonのMake時にmake: gmcs: No such file or directory　が発生する

Tags: unity3d, makefile

LitJsonのソースコードに修正を加え、Macのターミナルを開き
MakeFileのある場所までディレクトリ移動し、makeを実行したところ
下記のようなエラーがでました。

●エラー内容
make: *** [自分のフォルダ/litjson-0.9.0/build/make/../../bin/LitJson.dll] Error 1

binフォルダが無いのが原因だと思い、binフォルダを作成して再度makeを
実行したのですが同じエラーが発生しました。

パスに関係するエラーだと思うのですが
何が原因なのか教えていただけないでしょうか？

■LitJson
　https://github.com/lbv/litjson

■LitJson内のMakeFile
　https://github.com/lbv/litjson/blob/master/build/make/Makefile

■環境
　OSX_10.10.3